# How to suspend process inside the docker using keyboard command?

Tags: docker, suspend

I have a windows 10 with docker installed. I enter the docker container by `docker attach Container_ID`. Then I know how to detach (`ctrl+p, ctrl+q`). If I enter `top` command, and press `ctrl+c`, the `top` command will stop. 
However, when I press `ctrl+z`, I will be detached from the container rather than suspend the `top` command (put it to the background).

I tried to use `--sig-proxy=false`, it does not work. And I do not understand the direction of the proxy (host to guest or guest to host?) I know that SIGSUSP should be send to the process in the docker. But it seems that the docker did not receive the signal.

I am using the `cmd` in win10.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You just want top to continuously run in the background and have it come right back up when you re-attach to the container?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to suspend the process to background and re-visit it later. `top` is just an example. My real problem is running jupyter notebook in docker. I can launched it using `jupyter notebook`, however, I cannot suspend it using `ctrl+z`.